# Shave ceramic hole instead of re-cutting

Tags: faucet, sink, sinkhole

I have no earthly idea why the previous orders did this.

For our sink they cut the sides 1.5 inches (left), and the middle 1.25 inch.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Our new faucet comes with these to go into the hole as a bracket. But these are 1.25 inches as well. The sides fit obviously (being 1.5 inches wide) but the middle one doesn't fit.

I mean it barely doesn't fit. If i could shave even 1/16 or 1/8 of inch off the hole it would fit snug. BUT IT WOULD FIT!!!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a diamond blade to a few sinks to get past issues, but only cutting the edge to get better clearance for faucet mounting washers. A carefully wielded abrasive bit on a Dremel or regular variable speed drill may do you.

Do not get it too hot, it will crack.

Vibration will mess you up as well.

Looks like the mounting flange will cover any small chips that may occur.

Comment: Can you give me a little bit more detail on the type of dremel bit?

Comment: A 545 diamond wheel with arbor or a 952 Aluminum Oxide Grinding Stone